# How do I style a geoJSON FeatureCollection in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to style a geoJSON FeatureCollection using `L.geoJSON`, and I have been unsuccessful in deviating from the default style.

I've already tried the documentation for `L.geoJSON` (see below), as well as putting style properties directly into the geoJSON features. Both options have no effect on the display of the layer

```
//coordinates on map
var map = L.map('map').setView([29.76, -95.37], 10);
L.esri.basemapLayer('Gray').addTo(map);
var fromProjection = "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";
var toProjection = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ";
var myStyle = {
    "color": "#ff7800",
    "weight": 5,
    "opacity": 0.65
};
var myLayer = L.geoJSON(watersheds,{
                coordsToLatLng: function (p) {
                    p = proj4(fromProjection,toProjection,p);  // reproject each point
                    p = [p[1],p[0]]    // swap the values
                    return p;          // return the lat/lng pair
                }},{
                style: myStyle
}).addTo(map);
```

Expected result: My layer will be orange and slightly transparent

Actual result: My layer is the default blue color

(similar to this: http://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/e472886c83819e8459178a4a56548449)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

There's not great documentation on this, but the second argument of L.geoJSON is 'options'. I was unintentionally closing the argument after coordsToLatLong. The correct code for this case is pasted below.

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([29.76, -95.37], 10);
    L.esri.basemapLayer('Gray').addTo(map);
    var fromProjection = "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";
    var toProjection = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ";
    var myStyle = {
        "color": "#ff7800",
        "weight": 5,
        "opacity": 0.65
    };
    var myLayer = L.geoJSON(watersheds,{
                    style: myStyle,
                    coordsToLatLng: function (p) {
                        p = proj4(fromProjection,toProjection,p);  // reproject each point
                        p = [p[1],p[0]]    // swap the values
                        return p;          // return the lat/lng pair
                    }}).addTo(map);
```

you can check your answer by using console.log(myLayer.options)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//coordinates on map
    var map = L.map('map').setView([29.76, -95.37], 10);
    L.esri.basemapLayer('Gray').addTo(map);
    var fromProjection = "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";
    var toProjection = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ";
    var myStyle = {
        "color": "#ff7800",
        "weight": 5,
        "opacity": 0.65
    };
    myLayer = L.geoJson(watersheds, {
       onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
       layer.setStyle(feature.myStyle);

       }
    }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: See my answer below for the mistake I was making